# Hard to switch from Windows to Linux

Tags: dual-boot

I'm new to Linux but I am completely unsure if I want to switch to Linux. My parents say that my computer cannot run Linux. There are some programs that I want on PC.

Here are my specs:
Processor: Intel(R) Celron(R) CPU N2840 @ 2.16GHz 2.16 GHz
RAM: 2GB
System Type: Windows 64 Bit

What are the perks of Linux and can I install Windows if I don't like Linux?

Comment: Just like @grammargeek said, here is the [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/)  for uninstalling linux

Comment: Thanks for that! I knew it would come :) I'll go add that

Comment: You can run Linux freely... it just takes time to get used to it like to any other OS also. According to your specs I'd recommend Xubuntu.

Comment: Also specify what software do you want to run...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well this is always fun to say: **Your parents are WRONG!**

Your computer can *easily* run Linux. In fact, you don't need to decide on Linux or Windows, because you can have *both*! This is called dual booting and it is very simple. Basically, upon startup, you chose from a menu  (Called GRUB) whether you want to boot into Windows or Linux.

If you eventually decide you don't like Linux, removing Linux is very easy on a dual boot system. See [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/). If this link doesn't work, try [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160321133107/http://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/)

Answer (score 0):

Moving from Windows can be hard and the shock of a new system can sometimes put people of sticking with the new OS. All I would say is stay with it if you can as it will all be worth it in the end. You have the option to duel boot or you can go for a vm option. This is possibly the one that I would go for in your current situation. That way, you can keep the current Windows that you have and also try the new OS. From the sounds of it, your machine will be more than able to run Linux.

You can dip your toes, as they say, without going all the way. There could be problems with the duel boot and that may stuff up your original system. The vm option would be safer. Whatever you decide, remember to back up your data.

You can install Wine which will allow you to run your favourite programs from windows, whilst in Ubuntu. If you look around, you will probably find that there is a great selection of free Linux alternatives out there, that you can move over to.

As one of the Big Issue sellers was saying the other day I went past him "Give it a go, your mum will never know" lol.

Answer (score 0):

Going off what grammer geek said, you can easily have both windows and linux on your computer. I reccomend using rufus or the universal usb installer to create a bootable usb, it makes the process of setting up a dual boot very easy. The advantages and disadvantages vary by user, but here are the biggest advanteges I believe linux offers.

1. Computer programming: linux provides an open source platform that makes writing software less of a hassel.
2. Customizability: with the options available, you can make your desktop experience very personalized. I have so many keyboard shortcuts setup in my kubuntu install I barely have to use the mouse.

Disadvantages:

1. Slightly higher maintanence: This will depend a lot on what you plan to do with it, but in general i find linux to require a bit more effort than windows to make a pleasing experience.
2. Support and compatibilty: Dont get me wrong, in many areas linux is more compatable than windows, but in terms of every day desktop use, its probably going to be a bit harder to find the right drivers and such. This applies to gaming especially.

Obviously there are a lot more pros and cons, but i hope this helps you get a better idea of what your looking at. If you have windows 7, its really easy to set up a dual boot and try it out for yourself. Windows 8 is a little harder but still not too bad. There a plenty of tutorials. Best of luck.

Comment: Yay another Rufus lover!